# Is there a special command in the TortoiseSVN menu to clear svn-relation of the directory?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I linked a folder of mine with a Subversion repository. The aim was to sync my home personal folder and office personal folder.

Later on, I gave up.

Now, I want to delete the repository relation of this folder without any harm to content inside. I just want it back to be a standard Windows folder.

I tried searching and deleting all `.svn` folders on another SVN-releated folder before. But it didn't go well.

I am looking for a command such as "Cancel SVN relation".

Is there something like this?

**Possible duplicate:** ['Un-SVN' a working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183114/un-svn-a-working-copy)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183114/un-svn-a-working-copy

Answer (score 1):

Use `Export`.

Answer (score 1):

In TortoiseSVN you can export to the current directory. TortoiseSVN will then remove the .svn directories for you (after you confirm that this is what you want to do).

This is not a standard Subversion function, but it is the easiest way using TortoiseSVN. The recommended practice for all other clients is to export to a new directory.

Answer (score 0):

I usually just delete the hidden .svn folder inside the folder containing the stuff you want to disassociate with SVN.

Comment: You have to do that recursively, though.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting .svn folders should be enough. See this [link](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread61479.html) for a script that it will do the job for you. Copied from there:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /AD /S *.svn*') DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%G"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just F3, .svn delete all found folders. Or even better export