# is there anyway to clean up old svn directories and files from old source code tree

Tags: windows, svn

i have been sent a directory tree of source code that i want to import into my subversion repository.  The issue is that at some point this code was in a different subversion repository.  There are a huge number of directories and subdirectories and i basically want to clean up all of the subversion .svn folders before i attempt to import to a new repository and i dont want svn to get confused.

is there anyway to clean out a directory structure to remove all svn references?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`svn export` will produce a copy of the source tree without the `.svn` folders. Example:

```
svn export <old_project_root> <new_name_of_clean_directory>
```

I believe TortoiseSVN also has this capability from within a menu.

Comment: The issue with this is that "Files not under version control will not be copied."

Comment: If you use the Export menu in TortoiseSVN in an existing working copy, it will go through cleaning out all .svn files without touching anything else.  http://tortoisesvn.net/node/343

Comment: @Matthew: If "at some point this code was in a different subversion repository", it seems more likely that everything relevant would be versioned. Important point, regardless.

Answer (score 2):

In the root of the project, with GNU find:

```
find . -name .svn -execdir rm -r {} +
```

EDIT: Corrected, with thanks to rkulla.  -delete does not -delete non-empty directories.

Comment: Yes.  I'm assuming you have a UNIX-like system, with GNU find.

Comment: i am running this on windows . .

Comment: Well, you install it for Windows pretty easily.  There's a setup program at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/findutils.htm .  Of course there are other options.

Comment: The -delete option won't remove nonempty directories. Use this instead: find . -name .svn -exec rm -r {} +;

Comment: Thanks, rkulla.  I went with execdir because it's less susceptible to race conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Stefan, author of TortoiseSVN, has [a complete explanation here](https://web.archive.org/web/20101201061652/http://tortoisesvn.net/node/343). The gist of it is to use a built-in TortoiseSvn `right-click` helper to do the job like so:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tortoisesvn.net](http://tortoisesvn.net/files/unversion.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

For more possible solutions see the following question [‘Un-SVN’ a working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183114/un-svn-a-working-copy).

One answer contains a Windows batch script that will cleanup all .svn folders.