# How to send source code without SVN stuff?

Tags: java, svn

I worked on a project using SVN repository. Now I have to send the source code to the client but I want to send it without SVN directories (hidden .svn directories).

How can I do that?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183114/un-svn-a-working-copy

Comment: svn export the content to a directory that you can then .zip up into an archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `svn export`, see link for [more](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html)